# Use the Axiom of Completeness to prove the Cut Property

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

I know that the Axiom of Completeness states

> Every nonempty set of real numbers that is bounded above has a least upper bound.

Where a least upper bound, $s$, is defined as follow:
A real number $s$ is the least upper bound for a set $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ if it meets the following two criteria:

1. $s$ is an upper bound for $A$;
2. if $b$ is any upper bound for $A$, then $s\leq b$.

And I'm supplied with the following property (Cut Property):

> If $A$ and $B$ are nonempty, disjoint sets with $A\cup B = \mathbb{R}$ and $a < b$ for all $a\in A$ and $b\in B$, then there exists $c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x \leq c$ whenever $x \in A$ and $x\geq c$ whenever $x\in B$.

---

I am asked to:

1. Use the Axiom of Completeness to prove the Cut property; and
2. Use Cut Property to prove the Axiom of Completeness.

This seems to be right under my nose, but I'm not exactly sure what to assume for $(1)$.

Could anyone give me a push?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Suppose you have the axiom of completeness and assume you have $A$ and $B$ as in the statement of the cut property. Then, as $B$ is nonempty, $A$ has an upper bound. Let $c$ be the least upper bound for $A$.

1. For $a\in A$, $a\le c$, because $c$ is an upper bound for $A$;
2. For $b\in B$, $c\le b$, because $b$ is an upper bound for $A$ and $c$ is the *least* upper bound

Suppose you know the cut property. Consider a nonempty set $C$ with an upper bound. Then let
$$
A=\{x\in\mathbb{R}: x<c\text{, for some $c\in C$}\}
$$
and let $B$ be the complement of $A$. Since $C$ has an upper bound $b$, we have $b\notin A$, so $B$ is nonempty as well as $A$. The union of $A$ and $B$ is $\mathbb{R}$ by construction. Suppose $a\in A$ and $b\in B$. If $b\le a$, we have $b<c$ for some $c\in C$, so $b\in A$: a contradiction.

Now, the cut property provides $d$ so $a\le d$, for every $a\in A$, and $d\le b$, for every $b\in B$. Can you prove that $d$ is the least upper bound of $C$?

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that the reasoning behind "$A$ is nonempty" is: Since $C$ is nonempty, there exists at least one element $c$ so that the set real numbers strictly less than $c$ will be nonempty which is a subset of $A$?

Comment: @SalmanQureshi Yes, we must ensure that neither $A$ nor $B$ is empty.

Comment: I have been able to show that $d$ is the least upper bound of $A$. How to show that the least upper bound of $A$ and $C$ are same?

Comment: @SalmanQureshi Any upper bound of $C$ is also an upper bound of $A$, so the least upper bound of $C$ is $\ge$ than the least upper bound of $A$. Suppose $>$ holds and get a contradiction.

Comment: After all is said, I still can't seem to prove the contradiction. Can you write it out for me?

Comment: And there's a slight confusion. After constructing $A$ and $B$, I have shown that any upper bound $u$ of $C$ must be in $B$. Then, for any $a \in A$ and $b \in B$, if $b \le a$, then how do I draw the contradiction here? You haven't shown any connection between being an upper bound of $C$ and being an element of $B$.

Comment: > Can you prove that  is the least upper bound of ?
I think I don't understand what ={∈ℝ:<, for some ∈} means. "For some" to me could mean that c is an arbitrary point in C. I.e. there could be a point k in C such that k > c. How would this guarantee that d, which is the point where we cut R into A and B, is a least upper bound for C?

Comment: @TGO I don't understand, sorry: if you prefer, write $A=\{x\in\mathbb{R}:\exists c(c\in C\land x<c)\}$. In other words, $A$ is the set of all real numbers which are less than at least one member of $C$. This set is not the whole of $\mathbb{R}$, because if we take an upper bound $b$ of $C$, then $b\notin A$.

Comment: Sorry I was unclear. The thing I don’t understand is how the point “c” is chosen. E.g. if the set C is the open interval (-inf, 1), the “cut point” d would have to be equal to 1 (which is sup C), and A equal to C. But then point c would be in A contrary to the definition. Hope this doesn’t sound too stupid.

Comment: @TGO There is no choice of the point $c$. An real number $x$ belongs to $A$ if (and only if) *there exists* $c\in C$ such that $x<c$. Of course, once one exists, all $c'\in C$ such that $c<c'$ would do, but it's irrelevant. If you prefer this formulation, $A=\bigcup_{c\in C}(-\infty,c)$

Comment: Ah perfect. This notation helped me understand what you mean, thank you. So no matter whether $C = (-\infty, 1]$ or $C = (-\infty, 1)$, in both cases $A = (-\infty, 1)$ (as an example). Thank you. I don't think I would've slept tonight if I didn't understand this, lol

Comment: @TGO You're welcome!