# Assume $\mathbb{R}$ possesses the Cut Property and let E be a nonempty that is bounded above. Prove that sup E exists.

Tags: real-analysis

I feel like this should work:
    Let *B* be the set of all upper bounds of *E*. Then this set is also non-empty because *E* is bounded above. Then let *A* be the complement of B. Then a < b for all a $\in$ *A* and b $\in$ *B* because *B* is unbounded above. Also, *A* $\cup$ *B* = $\mathbb R$, so the Cut Property asserts that there exists a c $\in$ $\mathbb R$ such that a $\le$ c for all a $\in$ *A*, and c $\le$ b for all b $\in$ *B*. Then we see that c is an upper bound for $A$ because a $\le$ c for all a, and because c $\le$ b for any other upper bound b, c = sup $A$. (I feel like this should then extend to $E$ automatically from here?) Likewise c = inf B because c $\le$ b for all b, and a $\le$ c for all other lower bounds a. In an earlier problem I showed that if *E* is a set bounded above and the set *B* is the set of its upper bounds, sup *E* = inf *B*. Thus sup *E* exists.

I think I might be including some extraneous steps and didn't want to miss any details either so I wanted to check here. I found two similar answers but neither seemed to fully satisfy my suspicions.

Comment: If you found similar answer on Math.SE it is helpful to provide links.

Comment: Sorry. [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1616583/use-the-axiom-of-completeness-to-prove-the-cut-property?rq=1)  
[link2](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1721305/use-cut-property-to-prove-axiom-of-completeness?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Then $a<b$ for all $a \in A, b \in B$ because $B$ is unbounded above": this justification is wrong. Just because $B$ is unbounded above doesn't mean everything in its complement is smaller than everything in $B$. The justification you want is "if $a$ is not an upper bound for $E$, then there is $e \in E$ such that $a \leq e$; and for all $b \in B$ we have $e < b$; so $a \leq b$. And $A \cap B = \emptyset$ so in fact $a < b$".

$c$ is a lower bound for $B$ and an upper bound for $A$. So it is an upper bound for $E$, because if there were $e \in E$ with $c < e$, then $\frac{c+e}{2}$ cannot be in $B$ (indeed, it's not an upper bound for $E$, because it's less than $e$) so it must be in $A$, but this contradicts that $c$ is an upper bound for $A$.

Comment: Those were pretty much the two spots I felt were questionable. Thank you much for your help good sir.

Comment: I understand your point that $c$ is an upper bound for $A$. But how did you assume that $c$ might be an upper bound of $E$. Although it truly is and we see that justified by the contradiction we get. But how do I jump to the step of justifying $c$ to be an upper bound of $E$?

Comment: @SalmanQureshi I don't understand the question. I supposed that $c$ were not an upper bound for $E$, and then derived a contradiction; so concluded that $c$ is in fact an upper bound for $E$.

Comment: @PatrickStevens My question is why did you suppose $c$ is not an upper bound of $E$. :)

Comment: @PatrickStevens Do you understand my question now? Quoting from your answer: "$c$ is a lower bound for $B$ and an upper bound for $A$. So it is an upper bound for $E$, because ..." You wrote as if you deduced that $c$ is an upper bound for $E$ based on some previous information and now heading to justify it using a contradiction. How did you do that is exactly what I am asking.

Comment: @SalmanQureshi I still don't understand. I intuited that $c$ is an upper bound for $E$, and then went on to prove it by contradiction.

Comment: @PatrickStevens Ok, got it. Since this is a crucial theorem, I suspected everything must be very firmly based on logical deductions.